# Load more posts button and pagination at the same time

Tags: ajax, pagination

I need to have a button - load more posts - and pagination at the same time - first the button and pagination below it. I think the better way to do it is via admin-ajax.php. I can do one or the other but not both. In this code load more button works but pagination is not. And how to make pagination out of the ajax_home() loop. This is a rough version of my code:

functions.php -->

```
<?php add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_home','ajax_home');
    add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_home','ajax_home');
     
    function ajax_home(){  
     
    
        $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'posts_per_page' => 38,
            'paged'=> $_POST['paged'],
        ); 
    
     
        $wp_home_query = new WP_Query($args);
         
        if( $wp_home_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while( $wp_home_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_home_query->the_post(); 
        ?>
    
       <?php the_title(); ?>
    
     <?php endwhile; ?>
    
    
    <div class="nav-links text-center">
        <?php
        $total_pages = $wp_home_query->max_num_pages;
        if ($total_pages > 1)
        {
            $mid_size = 4; // default to 1 number each side
    
    // Check if we are on the first or last page
    $current_page = get_query_var('paged');
    if ( !$current_page || $current_page == $wp_home_query->max_num_pages ) {
        $mid_size = 2; // 2 numbers before/after the current page
    }
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'mid_size' => $mid_size,
                'base' => esc_url(get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%'),
                'format' => 'page/%#%',
                'current' => $current_page,
                'total' => $total_pages,
                'prev_next' => True,
                'prev_text' => __('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/arrow-left-page.svg" />'),
                'next_text' => __('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/arrow-right-page.svg" />'),
                'add_args'  => array()
            ));
        }
      
    ?>
    </div>
    
     
    <?php
    endif; 
     
        wp_die();
         }
```

custom.js -->

```
let currentPageHome = 1;

jQuery.ajax({
  dataType: "html",
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
  data: {
    'action': 'ajax_home',
    'paged': currentPageHome,
  }, 
  success: function (res2) { 
    currentPageHome++;
    jQuery('#home-posts').html(res2);
  }, 
 
 
   
});



let loadMoreButtonHome;

loadMoreButtonHome = jQuery('#load-more-home');

loadMoreButtonHome.on('click', function() { 
  
  jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
      'action': 'ajax_home',
      'paged': currentPageHome,
    }, beforeSend: function () {
      jQuery('.cb-loading-home').show();
      jQuery('.cb-loading-home').html('<div class="cb-search-loading">Loading...</div>');
  },
    success: function (res3) {
      jQuery('.cb-loading-home').hide();
    
      jQuery('#home-posts').fadeIn(400).append(res3);
      currentPageHome++;
      if (res3.trim().length === 0) {
        loadMoreButtonHome.hide();
        jQuery('.cb-no-results-home').show();
      } else {
        loadMoreButtonHome.show();
      }
         
    }
    
  });

  
});
```

html -->

```
<div id="home-posts"></div>
<div class="cb-loading-home text-center"></div>
<div id="load-more-home">Load more</div>
```